# Why is my drawable not being applied to my menu?

Tags: android, menu, android-drawable

I have an activity that has custom menu items to launch, The problem is, when I hit the button for menu, the popup has a transparent background. I tried changing it to a ActionBarActivity over Activity, but it doesn't have an override-able onMenuItemSelected.

So, to get around that, I applied this to my styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
 <item name="android:panelFullBackground">@drawable/customblackbox</item>
</style>
```

It didn't work, still have a transparent background. It's my only theme in the styles. Here's the custom black box xml that I created:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#151515"/>
<corners android:radius="0dp" />
<padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp"
       android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
<stroke android:color="#151515" android:width="1dp" />   
 </shape>
```

Why is the drawable not working?

EDIT:

Here is how I'm setting up my menu in my activity. The two IDs are just ints:

```
 @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(0, EDIT_ID, 0, "Edit Fencer");
    menu.add(0, DELETE_ID,  0, R.string.fencer_delete);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case EDIT_ID:
         //do other stuff
    .
    .
    .
]
```

To be clear, this is what is happening when I hit the menu options: 
[image]

Comment: if you remove this <item name="android:panelFullBackground">@drawable/customblackbox</item> do you get the same result ?

Comment: Yes. It has no effect.

Comment: so are you sure that you have to use this ->panelFullBackground

Comment: No, that is the suggestion that I found in SO to fix the problem. It did not work for me.

Comment: I am not trying to change the text color. I'm trying to change it so that the options menu is visible over the layout it is sitting on top of. As of now, the background is trasnparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else needs an answer in the future:

What solved this for me was to change it to an actionBarActivity, and remove the action bar during onCreate. Nothing else seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height and width of custom menu to match_parent.

Also share code related to custom menu as well.

Try following:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
 <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/customblackbox</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I'm not using a custom menu i.e. a XML drawable, I meant custom by the menu has items that I have added. I am using the native one.

Comment: Yeah, ' android:theme="@style/AppTheme" '